# Promise is not executing in synchronous way in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, synchronous

I'm beginner in NodeJs.We all know promise is also one of the method to execute in synchronous way in nodeJS.In my code it's not executing synchronously.can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code? I have attached the code below.and output what I have  gotten now.Any comments would be appreciate.Thanks in advance......

CODE:

```html
getUser(25)
    .then((user)=>{
        console.log(`User:`,user.username);
        getgithubRepo(user.username);
    })
    .then((repos)=>{
        console.log("Repos:",repos);
        getCommit(repos[1]);
    })
    .then((message)=>{
        console.log(`Final Message: ${message}`);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(`Reject: ${err}`);
});



function getUser(id){

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

        if(id === 25){

            setTimeout(()=>{

                console.log(`Id: ${id}`);

                console.log(`Reading a user from database`);

                resolve({id:id,username:'vigneshTokyo'});

            },3000);

        }
        else{

            setTimeout(()=>{

                console.log(`Your given Id is not found...`);

                reject(`User not found in database`);

            },3000); 
        }
    });
}


function getgithubRepo(username){

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

        if(username === "vigneshTokyo"){

            setTimeout(()=>{

                console.log(`Username: ${username}`);

                console.log(`Calling Github API...`);

                const repos=['vikirepo1','vikirepo2','vikirepo3'];

                resolve(repos);

            },2000);

        }
        else{

            setTimeout(()=>{

                console.log(`Repositories are not found of this username`);

                reject(`Repositories are not found of this username`);

            },2000);
        }

    });
}


function getCommit(repo){

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

        if(repo === "vikirepo2"){

            setTimeout(()=>{

                console.log(`Repository Name: ${repo}`);
        
                console.log(`Going to commit this ${repo}.....`);
               
                return resolve('Repo commited succesfully');
        
            },2000);

        }
        else{

            setTimeout(()=>{

                return reject('Repos not found in this account');
        
            },2000);

        }

    });

    
}
```

OUTPUT:

```html
Id: 25
Reading a user from database
User: vigneshTokyo
Repos: undefined
Reject: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
Username: vigneshTokyo
Calling Github API...

Expected output:

Id: 25
Reading a user from database
Resolve: { id: 25, username: 'vigneshTokyo' }
Username: vigneshTokyo
Calling Github API...
List of Repostories: [ 'vikirepo1', 'vikirepo2', 'vikirepo3' ]
Repository Name: vikirepo2
Going to commit this vikirepo2.....
Message: Repo commited succesfully
```

Comment: Promises work using `return` values - you need to `return` promises from inside `then` handlers for them to chain. I recommend considering `async/await`.

Comment: You have to return the `Promise` returned by the `getgithubRepo` (and all the other functions) from the `then` callback.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments.I have used return before the function names inside then method..It's working in synchronous way.fine....